# Basic problems with width and height of navigation using CSS

Tags: html, css

I started yesterday with learning HTML and got stuck with a (simple) example:

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <title>stylish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylish_sheet.css" />
</head>
<body>

<header> Header </header>

<nav>
    <p>short</p>
    <p>longernav</p>
    <p>verylongnavigation</p>
</nav>

<section> 
    <div class="entry"> <h1> Section 1 </h1> 
    <p>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>

    <div class="entry"> <h1> Section 2 </h1> 
    <p>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>

    <div class="entry"> <h1> Section 3 </h1> 
    <p>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>

    <div class="entry"> <h1> Section 4 </h1> 
    <p>  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
</section>

<footer> Footer </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.entry {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:15px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:250px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

header, footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
    height:20px;
}

footer {
    clear:both;
}

nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    height:100vh;
    width:10%;
    max-width:150px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}

section {
    width:80%;
    min-width:250px;
    max-width:100%;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Now I have 3 problems and one minor issue:

1) I want the min-width of the navigation to adapt to the longest text in it (in this case "verylongnavigation"). It doesn't matter if the text wraps. I set the max-width fix to 150px so I dont know what happens when the text is then actually longer than that. In this case the idea was that it still adapt to the text, i.e., text size has higher priority than max-width.

2) I want the height of the navigation to go from the header to the footer. It is colored lightgreyish but it never fills the total space. It seems height:100% only adapts to the text itself. I tried height:100vh but then the area gets higher than necessary, i.e., it gets bigger than the section part.

3) When I make the browser window width small then the "section" wraps below the "nav". How can I disable this s.t. I would have to scroll to the right to see the text in the sections?

4) The minor issue: for the header and the footer there is a small (~5px) white space to the left but not on the right. I tried to set width:100%-5px but it seems thats not possible. So I found margin-right:5px but this does nothing (whereas margin-top and margin-left does what I seek). Is there another way where I can merge relative sizes with absolute sizes or am I using it wrong?

Thank you in advanced,

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply remove both, `width` and `max-width` from `nav`. This way the menu background will always cover the longest text.
2. To set the height of the nav background to the same as the content, you either have to define both to the same height or use faux columns (more on this can be read on many documentation on the web, one of them is [this one](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)).
3. Using faux columns (as explained above) `section` would not wrap below `nav` anymore. Basically they would be 2 different columns that would stand side by side always.
4. Elements in CSS have default styling. To get rid of those, one usually 'resets' those values by setting them to 0 as follows:

   ```
   * {
       padding:0;
       margin:0
   }
   ```

   Here is some [more info on resetting css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: ah tanks a lot. 1) and 4) already helped. Gonna read the article tomorrow (seems bit more complicated).